# How can I retrieve my Geopoint object from firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I'm saving my current device location using Firestore's [Geopoint object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint).

On retrieving it, It comes as below (toString()):

`{geoPoint=GeoPoint { latitude=-1.2968733, longitude=36.8906349 }}`

How can I retrieve the latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the field is a GeoPoint type object, just fetch it as a GeoPoint type field, then use its getLatitude and getLongitude methods to access those values.  Don't bother converting it to a string.

```
GeoPoint gp = snapshot.getGeoPoint("your-field");
double lat = gp.getLatitude();
double lon = gp.getLongitude();
```